# Sum of all numbers in range from 0 to a given number that are divisible with 7

Tags: python, sum

First line would ask the user to give a number. The program should give a sum from 0 to that number of numbers that are divisible by 7.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions

Comment: Just googled "python sum numbers divisible by x" : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277824/sum-of-all-numbers-within-a-range-without-numbers-divisible-by-x-in-python

Comment: To know whether the number is divisible by 7, use: `num % 7 == 0`, if it returns true number is divisible by 7. Goodluck witht he code

Comment: How do I get the sum of numbers in the sequence?

Answer (score 0):

Without writing any code for you, I can say that you'll need to look into the `sum()` function, the modulo `%` and equality `==` operators, `input()`, and `range()`.

There are many wonderful tutorials on the basics of Python and programming in general, and you can find them pretty easily with a Google search.